# Adding markers to a Google Maps map from a source

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I decided to make a simple project to learn the Google Maps API. I'd appreciate a review of the code below. I'd like to know what I did right and wrong.

The code pulls data from one source and adds markers on a map via the Google Maps API. A working sample is located here: [www.seedtip.com](http://www.seedtip.com)

```
$(function() {
//var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var marketId = []; //returned from the API
    var allLatlng = []; //returned from the API
    var allMarkers = []; //returned from the API
    var marketName = []; //returned from the API
    var infowindow = null;
    var pos;
    var userCords;
    var tempMarkerHolder = [];

    //Start geolocation

    if (navigator.geolocation) {    

        function error(err) {
            console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
        };

        function success(pos){
            userCords = pos.coords;
        }

        // Get the user's current position
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
        //console.log(pos.latitude + " " + pos.longitude);
        } else {
            alert('Geolocation is not supported in your browser');
        }

    //End Geo location

//map options
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.09024, -100.712891),
    panControl: false,
    panControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT
    },
    zoomControl: true,
    zoomControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER
    },
    scaleControl: false,

};

//Adding infowindow option
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "holding..."
});

//Fire up Google maps and place inside the map-canvas div
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

//grab form data
$('#chooseZip').submit(function() { // bind function to submit event of form

    //define and set variables
    var userZip = $("#textZip").val();
    //console.log("This-> " + userCords.latitude);

    var accessURL;

    if(userZip){
        accessURL = "http://search.ams.usda.gov/farmersmarkets/v1/data.svc/zipSearch?zip=" + userZip;
    } else {
        accessURL = "http://search.ams.usda.gov/farmersmarkets/v1/data.svc/locSearch?lat=" + userCords.latitude + "&lng=" + userCords.longitude;
    }


        //Use the zip code and return all market ids in area.
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: accessURL,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (data) {

                 $.each(data.results, function (i, val) {
                    marketId.push(val.id);
                    marketName.push(val.marketname);
                 });

                //console.log(marketName);

                var counter = 0;
                //Now, use the id to get detailed info
                $.each(marketId, function (k, v){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        // submit a get request to the restful service mktDetail.
                        url: "http://search.ams.usda.gov/farmersmarkets/v1/data.svc/mktDetail?id=" + v,
                        dataType: 'jsonp',
                        success: function (data) {

                        for (var key in data) {

                            var results = data[key];

                            //console.log(results);

                            //The API returns a link to Google maps containing lat and long. This pulls it apart.
                            var googleLink = results['GoogleLink'];
                            var latLong = decodeURIComponent(googleLink.substring(googleLink.indexOf("=")+1, googleLink.lastIndexOf("(")));

                            var split = latLong.split(',');
                            var latitude = split[0];
                            var longitude = split[1];

                            //set the markers.    
                            myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);

                            allMarkers = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: myLatlng,
                                map: map,
                                title: marketName[counter],
                                html: 
                                        '<div class="markerPop">' +
                                        '<h1>' + marketName[counter].substring(4) + '</h1>' + //substring removes distance from title
                                        '<h3>' + results['Address'] + '</h3>' +
                                        '<p>' + results['Products'].split(';') + '</p>' +
                                        '<p>' + results['Schedule'] + '</p>' +
                                        '</div>'
                            });

                            //put all lat long in array
                            allLatlng.push(myLatlng);

                            //Put the marketrs in an array
                            tempMarkerHolder.push(allMarkers);

                            counter++;
                            //console.log(counter);
                        };

                            google.maps.event.addListener(allMarkers, 'click', function () {
                                infowindow.setContent(this.html);
                                infowindow.open(map, this);
                            });


                            //console.log(allLatlng);
                            //  Make an array of the LatLng's of the markers you want to show
                            //  Create a new viewpoint bound
                            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();
                            //  Go through each...
                            for (var i = 0, LtLgLen = allLatlng.length; i < LtLgLen; i++) {
                              //  And increase the bounds to take this point
                              bounds.extend (allLatlng[i]);
                            }
                            //  Fit these bounds to the map
                            map.fitBounds (bounds);


                        }
                    });
                }); //end .each
            }
        });

    return false; // important: prevent the form from submitting
});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty nice so far. The code is easy to read, clear, straightforward.

The single biggest problem is probably this:

> ```
> var mapOptions = {
>     // ... a bunch of fields here
>     scaleControl: false,  // <- remove that comma!
> };
> ```

Many nice browsers let you get away with it, but that comma at the end is incorrect syntax. In some browsers (and non-browsers like IE) this can crash the script with cryptic error messages (happened to me, wasn't fun).

---

When iterating over the fields of a JavaScript object, you have to check if the field really belongs to that object, like this:

```
for (var key in data) {
    if (!data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        continue;
    }
    // ... 
}
```

For more details, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object).

---

Declare variables in the smallest possible scope where they are used.
For example the `marketId` array is not used outside the AJAX call,
so it would have been better to declare there, and right before needed.
Same goes for `allLatlng`, `allMarkers`, and possible others too I didn't verify.

---

This URL appears multiple times with minor variations:

> ```
> accessURL = "http://search.ams.usda.gov/farmersmarkets/v1/data.svc/zipSearch?zip=" + userZip;
> ```

It would be better to define a `baseURL` to avoid duplicated string literals:

```
var baseURL = "http://search.ams.usda.gov/farmersmarkets/v1/data.svc";
```

---

It may seem a minor thing,
but the indentation is not consistent,
for example it's inexplicably reduced by one level at the start of `var mapOptions = ...`,
then after a couple of lines it goes back to normal.
It would improve readability to be consistent with that.

---

Unused local variable:

> ```
> var pos;
> ```

---

Unnecessary semicolon at the end of function declaration:

> ```
> function error(err) {
>     console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
> };
> ```

There's one more, at the end of the `for (var key in data) { ... };` loop.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just need to declare your image var and again in the function call:

```
//set the markers.    
myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);
var image = "http://static.scripting.com/glyphs2/" + iconname + ".png";                   
allMarkers = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map,
  icon: image,
  title: marketName[counter],
  html: 
   '<div class="markerPop">' +
    '<h1>' + marketName[counter].substring(4) + '</h1>' + //substring removes distance from title
    '<h3>' + results['Address'] + '</h3>' +
    '<p>' + results['Products'].split(';') + '</p>' +
    '<p>' + results['Schedule'] + '</p>' +
    '</div>'
});
```

You might also want to consider wrapping this in another function and applying Google Maps Geocoder, as you are pulling them on the fly.

Comment: Yeah, I was considering using the GeoCoder. I might do that in the future. Thanks